# Group by and Having Clause that uses multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, having

The `AND` condition in the below `Having` clause behaves like it filters the row even if one of the conditions is met when its supposed to be logical `AND` behavior.

```
with cte as 
( select 'A' as name , 10 as Classes , 11 as Fees union all
 select 'A' as name , 10 as Classes , 10 as Fees union all
  select 'A' as name , 10 as Classes , 10 as Fees union all
   select 'A' as name , 10 as Classes , 10 as Fees union all
    select 'A' as name , 10 as Classes , 10 as Fees union all
     select 'B' as name , 0 as Classes , 10 as Fees union all
      select 'B' as name , 0 as Classes , 10 as Fees union all
       select 'B' as name , 1 as Classes , 10 as Fees union all
        select 'B' as name , -10 as Classes , 10 as Fees union all
         select 'B' as name , 10 as Classes , 11 as Fees 
       )
       -- A has 50 rooms and 51 $ -- so it should not be returned
       -- B has 1 room and 51 $ and should be fetched
        -- why would the AND in the having clause  behave like a row level filter on only the indivigual column 
        -- instead of the combination
        -- The weird thing is the logic behaves as expected when using = but fails when using <>
       select name , sum(Classes) , sUM(Fees)
       from cte 
       group by name 
       having ( SUM(Classes) !=50) AND (sum(Fees) !=51  )
```

Here is the weird part if you replace the != with an = like shown below then it works fine

```
with cte as 
( select 'A' as name , 10 as Classes , 11 as Fees union all
 select 'A' as name , 10 as Classes , 10 as Fees union all
  select 'A' as name , 10 as Classes , 10 as Fees union all
   select 'A' as name , 10 as Classes , 10 as Fees union all
    select 'A' as name , 10 as Classes , 10 as Fees union all
     select 'B' as name , 0 as Classes , 10 as Fees union all
      select 'B' as name , 0 as Classes , 10 as Fees union all
       select 'B' as name , 1 as Classes , 10 as Fees union all
        select 'B' as name , -10 as Classes , 10 as Fees union all
         select 'B' as name , 10 as Classes , 11 as Fees 
       )
       -- A has 50 rooms and 51 $ -- so it should not be returned
       -- B has 1 room and 51 $ and should be fetched
        -- why would the AND in the having clause  behave like a row level filter on only the indivigual column 
        -- instead of the combination
        -- The weird thing is the logic behaves as expected when using = but fails when using <>
       select name , sum(Classes) , sUM(Fees)
       from cte 
       group by name 
       having ( SUM(Classes) =1) AND (sum(Fees) =51  )
```

Am I missing something when it comes to the way `Group by` works? I know I can get around the issue but I don't understand why it behaves this way.

This is what I get

[image]

This is what I am supposed to get

[image]

Comment: provide sample output from the queries and what should be expected, please

Comment: pls also provide what your db is and what kind of error you occur? is it just not returning the data you want or you didn't get query running?

Comment: MS SQL 2019 , no errors , just not getting the output as expected , the code looks correct so I just need to understand why it isn't working the way described in Docs

Comment: @user5785372 anyway OP `having ( SUM(Classes) !=50) AND (sum(Fees) !=51  )` the last part block the  `sum(Fees) = 51`  arn't it ,you should use `or` not `and`

Comment: OR would mean that if either sum Classes or Sum fees is not matching the row is returned . I need to get the row when both are not matched

Comment: if it helps think of it like finding students where Classes !=0 and fees !=0 , but if a student has a non zero value for either then it should be fetched.

Comment: @user5785372 then nothing match cause the desire result is `B 1 51` how can a `51` appear when you declare `having sum(Fees) !=51`

Comment: the query is using the AND Condition with Classes too. If it was Only sum(fees) !=51 then your correct and B should not be displayed but when the clause is (Classes != 50 AND Fees != 51 )-- B  should be part of the output since it clearly doesn;t meet the criteria of Logical AND NOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after some discuss, try use this

```
 having not(SUM(Classes) =50 AND sum(Fees) =51)
```

and OP you gotta think twice when you writing boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to not understand boolean logic.

without the having clause,  those are your results

```
A   50  51
B   1   51
```

With

```
 having ( SUM(Classes) !=50) AND (sum(Fees) !=51  )
```

You ask: *show me all rows for which classes are not 50 AND fees are not 51*.

The AND is important.

Now look again at the results without having clause and ask yourself why would you expect anything to be returned?

Since both lines have a fee=51, nothing is returned because you ask for rows having fee different than 51.

This is a known mind trap from Boolean logic when you cumulate NOT (or <> !=) with ANDs. Generally speaking you should rarely do that. When you have several NOT, you should cumulate them with OR, not AND.